# Media exceptions on Google Chrome not editable

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

According to this:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1

you should be able to edit the exceptions by "Click the "Hostname pattern" field and enter the domain name for which you want to create an exception."

I am not able to enter/edit exception in that field.

I have Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m 
My OS: Windows 7

Working for Image exception and not working for Media exception

[image]

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you provide a screenshot of the dialog?

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: @onetwo12 Huh. I see the same behavior (Chrome 32, Windows 7).

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't looking at the Media exceptions. I get the same behavior you get, I can only add exceptions for specific hosts through the permissions panel on the site itself.